# Why MonoDevelop and Unity3D doesn't knows Application.LoadLevel();?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make transition to the next level, but my editor says:

```
Assets/next.cs(5,30): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Using Unity 4.7.2, C# code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class next : MonoBehaviour {

    Application.LoadLevel("1");

}
```

I expected NO ERRORS in this situation, but I have "barking" editor :(

Comment: Also, follow naming convention and name your class with a Leading Upper Case letter.

Comment: OP, remember to upvote and mark as validate the answer who help you sort out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I am not a Unity dev, but since your problem is a C# error... lets fix it. Try adding a constructor to the class next:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class next : MonoBehaviour {

    public next() {
       Application.LoadLevel("1");
    }
}
```

You can show the problem like this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var next = new next();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

    public class next
    {
        //public next()
        //{
            Console.WriteLine("1");
        //}
    }
}
```

Now if you uncomment the constructor, it will work as expected. The error is gone.

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IbnFHk)

Comment: Monobehaviour classes do not accept constructors, they cant be instantiated

Comment: @Innat3 I didnt remember. I didnt use unity since school. Thank you for pointing out. If you post a answer actually fixing OP's problem, I will delete my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call it there, it has to be done inside a method

So you can either do it in the `Awake()` or `Start()`, or define your own. In addition I don't know which Unity version you are using but `Application.LoadLevel()` is deprecated, you should be using `SceneManager.LoadScene()`. For example:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class next : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private void GoToSceneOne()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("1"); // SceneManager.LoadScene("1");
    }
}
```